# How can I restrict the location of the separator in JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

Is there a way to restrict the location of the separator of a `JSplitPane`?
I want to prevent it from ending up near either end. Whether the user drags
the separator, or it is reset due to window resize.

Answer (score 5):

See the [Swing tutorial about `JSplitPane`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html). More specifically the [Divider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html#divider) section contains an example where the separator can not be dragged towards the end. Basically it comes down to setting the minimum size of the components contained in the split pane

Comment: +1 for the tutorial link and pointing out that the secret is that the split pane respects the minimum size of a component.